# Using recursion combinations to subset array

Tags: c++, r, recursion, rcpp

I recently posted a poor question on how to use recursion to estimate all combinations of lower triangle in C++. I managed to find a recursive algorithm that given an array of size n, generates and prints all possible combinations of r elements in array. I've employed this function using Rcpp in R. I've then written a loop around this function to get all the subsets of combinations r to r + n.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int recursive(IntegerVector arr, IntegerVector data, int start, int end, int index, int r)
{
    if (index == r)
  {
    for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
        printf("%d ", data[j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
    {
    data[index] = arr[i];
    recursive(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
    }

}
```

R code with five groups:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp('recursive2.cpp')
nComm <- 5
r <- c(2:nComm)
n <- nComm
arr <- c(1:nComm)
dat <- c(1:nComm)
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
   recursive(arr, dat, 0, n-1, 0, r[i])
}
1 2 
1 3 
1 4 
1 5 
2 3 
2 4 
2 5 
3 4 
3 5 
4 5 
1 2 3 
1 2 4 
1 2 5 
1 3 4 
1 3 5 
1 4 5 
2 3 4 
2 3 5 
2 4 5 
3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 5 
1 2 4 5 
1 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Currently, this just prints the subsets of combinations I need to estimate my dissimilarities. I'd like to be able to  remove the loop and use it as a single Rcpp function/script. With the end goal to be able to use the subsets (currently printed combinations) as way to subset rows in an array. Which will be used to calculate the intersect between vectors. So `1 2` will be used to compare rows `1` and `2` in an array. And so forth.